# Amazon AWS load balancers IP address list

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

Using AWS, is there any way to find a list of IP addresses of all the Load Balancers or searching for a specific IP address between all the Load Balancers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DescribeLoadBalancers` API call to get `DNSName` of each load balancer. Then you can translate a DNS name to one or more IP addresses of that load balancer with `dig` or a software library.

After you retrieved a list of all IP addresses for all load balancers, you can do a reverse search by IP. Keep in mind that IP address(es) of an ELB can in theory change over time.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/2012-06-01/APIReference/API_DescribeLoadBalancers.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sergey. The problem arises when there are 200 ELB and during an investigation for a strange request, you face an unknown IP address. Using suggested method it takes forever to find the source.